# "Correct" location for Windows service data?

Tags: windows-services

Since a Windows service doesn't run within a user context, what is the "correct" place to put writable data?  Is there such a location that is version-independent (I'm thinking Vista vs XP)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A folder off the AppData folder - use SHGetFolderPath() and get the CSIDL_APPDATA path.

Actually - a service should use CSIDL_COMMON_APPDATA.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of writable data?

Normally, an application would use either a database or a flat file for actual data. For error messages and the like, use the Event Log.

Comment: It's user data, stored as flat text files, but not specific to a user.